# QGIS data is not shown while opening a .qgis file

Tags: qgis

I am trying to load a module project with .qgis from my phone from a program called Locus GIS project called "power network", by me at house it loads on my win 10 pc.
[image]

But my ubuntu pc at work the data won't load. The layers load already and I can plot new data, points, elements but the saved "network power" won't load.

```
2021-04-06T16:02:22     WARNING    SQLite-Fehler:no such module: rtree
  SQL: SELECT "ROWID", AsBinary("geometry") FROM "power_lines_110kv" WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT pkid FROM "idx_power_lines_110kv_geometry" WHERE xmin = 10.37316050898623132 AND ymin = 50.98134542764638866)
2021-04-06T16:02:22     WARNING    SQLite-Fehler:no such module: rtree
  SQL: SELECT "ROWID", AsBinary("geometry") FROM "power_lines_110kv" WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT pkid FROM "idx_power_lines_110kv_geometry" WHERE xmin = 10.37316050898623132 AND ymin = 50.98134542764638866)
2021-04-06T16:02:22     WARNING    SQLite-Fehler:no such module: rtree
  SQL: SELECT "ROWID", AsBinary("geometry") FROM "power_lines_380_kv" WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT pkid FROM "idx_power_lines_380_kv_geometry" WHERE xmin = 10.37316050898623132 AND ymin = 50.98134542764638866)
2021-04-06T16:02:22     WARNING    SQLite-Fehler:no such module: rtree
  SQL: SELECT "ROWID", AsBinary("geometry") FROM "power_lines_380_kv" WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT pkid FROM "idx_power_lines_380_kv_geometry" WHERE xmin = 10.37316050898623132 AND ymin = 50.98134542764638866)
2021-04-06T16:02:22     WARNING    SQLite-Fehler:no such module: rtree
  SQL: SELECT "ROWID", AsBinary("geometry") FROM "power_poles" WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT pkid FROM "idx_power_poles_geometry" WHERE xmin = 10.37316050898623132 AND ymin = 50.98134542764638866)
2021-04-06T16:02:22     WARNING    SQLite-Fehler:no such module: rtree
  SQL: SELECT "ROWID", AsBinary("geometry") FROM "power_poles" WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT pkid FROM "idx_power_poles_geometry" WHERE xmin = 10.37316050898623132 AND ymin = 50.98134542764638866)
```

Comment: what do u call a 'module project' ? what do u call a .qgis file ? What do u have on your 'phone' ?

Comment: Your Ubuntu SQLITE database may have been compiled without R*Tree support. I'd look there (maybe reinstall sqlite). Possibly, Ubuntu is looking at a different version of SQLITE than the one that QGIS should be using.

Comment: on my phone a program called Locus GIS, where there is a sample project called power network

Comment: ok, how do reinstall this SQLITE  ??

Comment: Check online. It's a very well known application. You may need to install from source in order to get the right libraries, like Rtree. sqlite.org/rtree.html shows the way. You may be able to reinstall the right version with the Ubuntu package manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to load it by going to browser inside QGIS and then choosing that project and choosing the single layers inside the project though the browser.